# Html2canvas - how to capture all the div?

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I'm using html to canvas for capture div 
Here is my code :

```
 $scope.testCanvas = function()
            {
    html2canvas([document.getElementById('test')], {
                          onrendered: function(canvas) {
                              $("#divtest").append(canvas);
                          }
                        });
                });
}

    <div id="test">
    <article id="art2" class="p-Fitness p-Tile u-md-spaceTop p-FitnesssecurityPatch" >
        <section class="p-Tile-section">
            <div class="p-Fitness-impact"></div>
            <div class="p-Fitness-securityGraph"></div>
        </section>
   </article>
   <article id="art2" class="p-Fitness p-Tile u-md-spaceTop p-Fitness-securityPatch" >
        <section class="p-Tile-section">
            <div class="p-Fitness-impact"></div>
            <div class="p-Fitness-securityGraph"></div>
        </section>
    </article>
    </div>

    <div id="divtest">
    </div>
```

The issue is that just a part of the div is captured the part that visible in the screen - as screenshot .
I need to capture all the div - any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You are just accessing the div with `Id` which will give you only a single element. `To capture all the divs you can use class selector`. add a class to all your divs let say `class = 'test'`. then you can do this.

```
html2canvas(document.getElementsByClassName('test'), {....
```

So what you are doing is replacing this

```
[document.getElementById('test')] -- array with one element
```

With

```
  document.getElementsByClassName('test')  -- array of selected elements.
```

Comment: I get an error : node.setAttribute is not a function

Comment: also if I changed it to document.body - just the part that visible in the screen is captured

Comment: `document.body` ?? where are you using it?